# extract users from given list of groups and extract the data to every new group name in text using powershell

Tags: powershell

Facing issue in output-file commandlet while extracting user list from given list of groups. I need each time a new text file to be generated in a Text format with the name of the groups given in the content list and data which is generated each time should be in that text file.

```
$grp= Get-Content 'C:\Users\p731400a\Desktop\groups.txt'
$grpdata= @()
$grpname=@()
foreach($grps in $grp)
{
    $grps
    $data= get-qadgroupmember $grps | Select-Object samaccountname | ft -AutoSize
    $grpname +=$grps
    $grpdata+= $data
}
Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\p731400a\Desktop\$grps.txt -InputObject $grpdata
```

Comment: what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I am trying to collect members of the groups given in a text format, and for each group I trying to get a new text output file with the group name and its corresponding data. I need help @ Out-File -FilePath C:\Users\p731400a\Desktop\$grps.txt -InputObject $grpdata area.

Comment: show example of the `group.txt` file and what is the desired output

Comment: xxxx-ServiceAccounts, xxxx-Server-Administrators
Let say these two are our groups of which I need an output xxxx-ServiceAccounts.txt and xxxx-Server-Administrators.txt and each group should contain its members in the text files.

Comment: Is the only problem you have with your 'Out-File' line? Does the 'ForEach' loop work correctly?

Comment: I think you need `Select-Object -ExpandProperty samaccountname`. Also, put `C:\Users\p731400a\Desktop\$grps.txt` in between double-quotes. Are you sure the group names do not contain invald filename characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in the input file the group names are stored each on a separate line, this should do it:

```
# read the input file as string array and loop through the list
Get-Content 'C:\Users\p731400a\Desktop\groups.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    # the $_ automatic variable here represents one group name at a time

    # add the `-Indirect` switch to get group members recursively when using 'Get-QADGroupMember'
    $members = Get-QADGroupMember $_ -Type 'user' -Indirect | 
               Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

    # or use 
    # $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive | 
    #            Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } | 
    #            Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

    #output on screen:
    Write-Host ("{0}`r`n{1}" -f $_, ('-' * $_.Length)) -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $members

    #output to file:
    $members | Add-Content -Path "C:\Users\p731400a\Desktop\$_.txt"
}
```

Hope that helps